# I am using the upload function of codeigniter but how do I attach the image uploaded on the server once I edit that item?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I have been successful in using the [File Uploading Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) to upload my files on the server (mostly images).

My problem is when I need to update that specific item, I need to browse for photo again. Is there a way I can just attach the image uploaded already in the server to my upload button? I am thinking to make a media page like that of the wordpress but is there any starting point that anyone knows who can point me to? Thanks so much!

Comment: where are you attaching it? Can you rephrase your question, as its not all that clear to at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field...check this example

**View**

```
<?php echo form_upload("vLogo", $campaign->vLogo , "id='vLogo'"); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden("vLogo_old", $campaign->vLogo , "id='vLogo_old'"); ?>
```

**Controller**

(Edit function)

```
//The way you do when you click on browse and select a file
if(isset($_FILES['vLogo']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['vLogo']['tmp_name']))
{

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            // Initialaizing Logo upload
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('vLogo')){
                $logo_error = array('vLogo' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            }
            else{
                $data1 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            }
}

else
{
//The browse filed is empty..So hidden input is taken 
     $data1['upload_data']['file_name'] = $post['vLogo_old'];
}
```